# System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException "Identity check failed for outgoing message."

Tags: wcf

The error I am getting is:

```
Identity check failed for outgoing message. The expected DNS identity of the remote endpoint was 'MYSERVER' but the remote endpoint provided DNS claim 'myserver.mycompany.com'. If this is a legitimate remote endpoint, you can fix the problem by explicitly specifying DNS identity 'myserver.mycompany.com' as the Identity property of EndpointAddress when creating channel proxy.
```

I have googled and found lots of problem getting this but none of the solutions have worked for me.

My questions 1) where exactly does the 'expected DNS identity' come from and 2) where is the DNS claim coming from?

From what I can tell the answer to question #2 is the  with the  element.

One thing that is different from the other posts I have seen is that this only broken on one of our servers so I am thinking this might be a DNS issue with this particular server.

Comment: Could we see your config please?

Comment: As I said this is working with all of the other server environments that it is running in and so it isn't really configuration that is the problem. If I could just find out the answers to the two questions (especially #1) I might be able to figure out what is different about this server. I can say that this particluar server everything DOES work if I install the certificates without the dns suffix (i.e. myserver vs myserver.mycompany.com).